# How to update the children of a post?

Tags: front-end, wp-update-post, posting

i found nothing about it in the WP reference and Google, so i ask you: I want to update a post by a form - and with it its children.

```
      $post = array(

            'ID'             => $mainid,  
            'post_status'   =>   'wartend'
        );
        $lead = wp_update_post($post);



$children = get_children( $mainid );

foreach ($children as $child){
    wp_update_post(
    array(
        'ID' => $child, 
        'post_status'   =>   'wartend',
        'post_parent' => $mainid
    )
);
}
```

The post is getting updated, but not the children.

Comment: What is the type of these posts?

Comment: Its a custom post type ^^ i didnt liked woocommerce, so i wrote a own shopping solution with custom fields and custom post type. Was more affort than i thought, but works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_children` returns an array of post objects by default:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/

So you would have to use `'ID' => $child->ID`, in this case... also my want to wrap the foreach with `if (count($children) > 0) {}` to prevent possible errors where there are no children. ie:

```
$children = get_children( $mainid );

if (count($children) > 0) {
    foreach ($children as $child){
        wp_update_post(
            array(
                'ID' => $child->ID, 
                'post_status'   =>   'wartend',
                'post_parent' => $mainid
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no probs @Plato, if this solved your problem feel free to mark answer as correct ;-)